# Checking if array exists within multidimensional array - no looping - unknown depth

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I need to do fast lookups to find if an array exists in an array. If I knew the depth of the array It would be easy - and fast!

```
$heystack['lev1']['lev2']['lev3'] = 10; // $heystack stores 10,000s of arrays like this

if(isset($heystack[$var1][$var2][$var3])) do something...
```

How would you do this dynamically if you don't know the depth? looping and searching at each level will be too slow for my application.

Comment: You want to check if `$heystack[$var1][$var2][$var3]` is an array? Like using `is_array($heystack[$var1][$var2][$var3])`?

Comment: If you don't know the depth/position of elements you might try [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

Comment: by "not knowing the depth" do you mean you don't know the position of $var1 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Maybe for you `in_array()` (allows search array in array) will help somehow... And about the depth... are the all of the arrays in array same depth?

Answer (score 2):

Your question has already the answer:

```
if (isset($heystack[$var1][$var2][$var3]))
{
   # do something...
}
```

If you don't know the how many `$var1 ... $varN` you have, you can only do it dynamically which involves either looping or `eval` and depends if you need to deal with string or numerical keys. This has been already asked and answered:

- Loop and Eval: **[use strings to access (potentially large) multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7003559/367456)** (and that's only one of the many)

If you are concerned about speed, e.g. if the array is always the same but you need to query it often, create a index first that has compound keys so you can more easily query it. That could be either done by storing all keys while traversing the array recursively:

```
class CompoundKeys extends RecursiveIteratorIterator
{
    private $keys;
    private $separator;
    public function __construct($separator, RecursiveIterator $iterator, $mode = RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST, $flags = 0)
    {
        $this->separator = $separator;
        parent::__construct($iterator, $mode, $flags);
    }
    public function current()
    {
        $current = parent::current();
        if (is_array($current))
        {
            $current = array_keys($current);
        }
        return $current;
    }
    public function key()
    {
        $depth = $this->getDepth();
        $this->keys[$depth] = parent::key();
        return implode('.', array_slice($this->keys, 0, $depth+1));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$it = new CompoundKeys('.', new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
$compound = iterator_to_array($it, 1);
isset($compound["$var1.$var2.$var3"]);
```

Alternatively this can be done by traversing recursively and referencing the original arrays values:

```
/**
 * create an array of compound array keys aliasing the non-array values
 * of the original array.
 *
 * @param string $separator
 * @param array $array
 * @return array
 */
function array_compound_key_alias(array &$array, $separator = '.')
{
    $index = array();
    foreach($array as $key => &$value)
    {
        if (is_string($key) && FALSE !== strpos($key, $separator))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Array contains key ("%s") with separator ("%s").', $key, $separator));
        }
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $subindex = array_compound_key_alias($value, $separator);
            foreach($subindex as $subkey => &$subvalue)
            {
                $index[$key.$separator.$subkey] = &$subvalue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $index[$key] = &$value;
        }
    }
    return $index;
}
```

Usage:

```
$index = array_compound_key_alias($array);
isset($index["$var1.$var2.$var3"]);
```

Comment: I just want to mention that isset($heystack[$var1][$var2][$var3] will fail for a given array which has the keys $var1 and $var2 but not $var3. Instead $var3 will converted to a string and this will return the first char of the value in $var2.
So isset will return true but $key3 doesn't exist!

// For knowing the depth and the keys
if(is_array($heystack[$var1][$var2]) && isset($heystack[$var1][$var2][$var3])) ...

Comment: Actually `isset`  will return also `false` when the element exists but is set to `null`. That are common caveats. You showed a solution for the problem that can happen for the wrong implementation of [substring access](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), for the isset problem it's [`array_key_exists`](http://de.php.net/array_key_exists).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need *some* sort of looping but you won't need to traverse the entire depth. You can simply use a function that does the equivalent of `$heystack[$var1][$var2][$var3]`, but dynamically:

```
$heystack['lev1']['lev2']['lev3'] = 10;

echo getElement($heystack, array('lev1', 'lev2', 'lev3')); // you could build second parameter dynamically

function getElement($array, $indexes = array())
{
    foreach ($indexes as $index) {
        $array = $array[$index];
    }

    return $array;
}

// output: 10
```

You'll need to put in some defense mechanisms to make the function more robust (for elements/indexes that don't exist) but this is the basic approach.