# Setting PHP multidimensional session variable in function

Tags: php

Say I have a function called `set_session_variable` that looks like:

```
function set_session_variable($name, $value) {
    // ...write value to the specified path 
}
```

How would I write this function (without using an `eval`) so that I can do something like:

```
set_session_variable('foo', 'bar'); // Would set $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar'; 
set_session_variable('foo[bar][baz]', 'blah'); // Would set $_SESSION['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'blah';
```

Comment: Please explain, how do you want to retrieve foo. First you set foo to bar. At this point say `foo` is a string. Next you set `foo[bar][baz]` to blah. What behaviour do you expect at this point? Do you want to convert `foo` from string to array (such that `foo[bar][blaz]` has value blah)? Or $_SESSION['foo'] gives you array such that $_SESSION['foo']['bar']['baz'] == 'blah?

Comment: I've updated my question to be a little more clear as to how I would like the $_SESSION variable to be written. At this point I'm not so much concerned w/ getting the variable as setting it.

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest, that you won't use

```
set_session_variable('foo[bar][baz]', 'blah');
```

but instead

```
set_session_variable('foo', array('bar'=>array('baz' => 'blah')));
```

Additionally, you don't need a function call for that at all:

```
$_SESSION['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'blah';
```

You can change the implementation of `$_SESSION` with the [*session save handler*](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler).

If you're only concerned how you could parse a string like `'foo[bar][baz]'`, this has been asked before, for example [**use strings to access (potentially large) multidimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7003559/367456).

Comment: The whole point of my function is to abstract the whole process so that I don't have to interact w/ the $_SESSION variable directly

Comment: You only use a global function instead for which you even change the way to interact in a non-standard way (only to put `$_SESSION` in there, I'm pretty sure). Anyway, you see the second example-line of code and the linked question/answer. Both should fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

A more relevant question is why you need a function at all. Function calls have a cost, and the function doesn't appear to do useful work.

Example assignments:

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
$_SESSION['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'blah';
$foo['bar']['baz'] = 'blah';
$_SESSION['foo'] = $foo;
```

In direct answer to your question: You could parse the value of $name within set_session_variable() using the PCRE module and a regular expression.

Even simpler and faster would be parsing it with sscanf() provided you are able and willing to impose a convention on the naming of array keys.

A cleaner alternative function:

```
$array['bar']['baz'] = 'blah';
set_session_variable('foo', $array);
function set_session_variable($key, $val) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to solve this is to mimic function overloading, example in this post -> [PHP function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697705/php-function-overloading)

Another way is to add one string argument to your function, with your array indices delimited.
For example: set_session_variable('foo', 'bar', 'baz;key');
Which saves the value 'bar' into foo['baz']['key'].

All you have to do is tear the 3rd argument apart (i use ; as delimiter here).