# Eval and array index as variable

Tags: php, eval

I've made a topic about trying to use an array index as a variable name previously, and received one answer that interested me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466815/php-variable-variables-with-array-key).

One of the answers suggested using eval(), although didn't recommend it due to its potential security issues.

```
$string = 'welcome["hello"]';
eval('$' . $string . " = 'thisworks';");

// This also works : eval("$$string = 'thisworks';");

// I could then print the array keys value like this
print( $welcome["hello"] ); // Prints 'thisworks'
```

However, this solution is the simplest, and is probably the most appropriate for what I want to achieve. I am actually working on a Wordpress admin panel, full of various options the user can set. Each option is set through a variable containing a multi-dimensional array, like this (only much larger):

```
$options = array(
 array(
  'id' => 'option_id', // The name of the input field
  'type' => 'text', // Input type
  'value' => 'some value here' // Input value
 )
);
```

When the user saves the options, a function fires, creating an array out of all the various input values and saving them into the database. Like below, although highly stripped down:

```
foreach ( $options as $o ) {
 if ( isset( $_POST[ $o[ 'id' ] ] ) ) {
  $settings[ $o[ 'id' ] ] = $_POST[ $o[ 'id' ] ];
 }
}
```

Some of the options from the multi-dimensions options variable, are to be saved as a part of an array, instead of a string. These options contain square brackets in their ID's, like 'option_id[value1]'.

This is where things get complicated. Currently, I am having to send the ID through a function that checks for the square brackets [], then telling the save function what to do with it appropriately (save as an array or string).

This is why the eval solution is ideal. It allows me to create a variable that's already an array and contains the index, without having to use other functions to disect the ID. It severely reduces a long winded process, or so I believe.

So in essence, is there a safer, similar way I can go about using eval, or using alternative functionality. What are the dangers of using eval in the way above? Can malicious code be executed in the context used above? Surely executing code before a $ would cause PHP errors?

Comment: It's important to note the source of the strings in assessing the potential danger of `eval`. Since the strings are user generated (you don't have 100% control over them), eval is out of the question.

Comment: I actually came across this very issue recently in an attempt to "fix" `$_POST` data by parsing the keys for brackets by reading `php://input` so I could make arrays (PHP does some [weird things](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#81080) to certain input keys).

Comment: you should elaborate on the whole "save some as an array, save some as a string stuff". It's not clear what you're doing. give fully fleshed out examples.

Comment: I get the feeling you've already picked the wrong solution. What are you *really* trying to do? Save some user settings? How are you saving this to the database, serialized? Needs more context for a good answer that will really help you, if that's what you're interested in. If you just want to solve this little puzzle, then that's another thing.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. @Wesley, I haven't actually used the solution but I wanted to see if it was possible to get it working in a secure manner, as it seemed like the best way to go about it. Did you manage to come up with anything to "fix" the $_POST? In essence, the reason why the ID has be searched for []'s is because $_POST[ 'option_id[value1]' ] doesn't work. If it did, there would be no problem. Yes, I am trying to save some user settings, but some of them need to be saved as arrays, and various inputs allow the user to change the value of one of the arrays properties.

Comment: Simplest solution I can think of is `json_encode` the config array before saving, then `json_decode` it for reading. I just don't understand why you can't do something like that. And no, I didn't bother with the $_POST "fix", it seemed like such a hack that I decided right off the bat it wasn't worth it.

Comment: The array being saved is constructed from an empty array. As above, the foreach loop goes through each option ID and sees if it has been posted (using $_POST), then adds it to the array to be saved. Option ID's with square brackets won't work correctly with $_POST, hence why I have to use a function to check for the [], extract the key, and use something like $_POST[ $id_without_brackets ][ $key ]. I'm not really sure how json_encode could be used, but that's because my PHP knowledge doesn't stretch that far.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but I *think* it would actually be safe to use `eval()` because while the contents of the variable are user generates, the *names* (which is what you are passing to `eval()`) are not. Although you would generate a lot of warnings about undefined variables and undefined constants...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using eval in this way seems like a hack to me and is unlikely to be performant. Why not use variable variables to achieve the same thing?

```
$string = 'welcome';
$key = "hello";

${$string}[$key] = "this works better";
print( $welcome["hello"] ); // Prints 'this works better'
```