# Using array value with index as Variable Variable

Tags: php, variable-variables

The title may be a little confusing. This is my problem:

I know you can hold a variable name in another variable and then read the content of the first variable. This is what I mean:

```
$variable = "hello"
$variableholder = 'variable'
echo $$variableholder;
```

That would print: "hello". Now, I've got a problem with this:

```
$somearray = array("name"=>"hello");
$variableholder = "somearray['name']"; //or $variableholder = 'somearray[\'name\']';
echo $$variableholder;
```

That gives me a PHP error (it says $somearray['name'] is an undefined variable). Can you tell me if this is possible and I'm doing something wrong; or this if this is plain impossible, can you give me another solution to do something similar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mixing variable name and array access here. possible duplicate of [use strings to access (potentially large) multidimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003559/use-strings-to-access-potentially-large-multidimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, I could only think of something like this:

```
<?php 
    // literal are simple
    $literal = "Hello";
    $vv = "literal";
    echo $$vv . "\n";
    // prints "Hello"


    // for containers it's not so simple anymore
    $container = array("Hello" => "World");
    $vv = "container";

    $reniatnoc = $$vv;
    echo $reniatnoc["Hello"] . "\n";
    // prints "World"
 ?>
```

The problem here is that (quoting from [php: access array value on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31942/89391)):

> the Grammar of the PHP language only allows subscript notation on the end of variable expressions and **not expressions in general**, which is how it works in most other languages.

Would PHP allow the subscript notation anywhere, one could write this more dense as

```
echo $$vv["Hello"]
```

---

Side note: I guess using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php) [isn't that sane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4273378/89391) to use in production.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work with my current problem (I should have talk about it in my question, but I wanted the question to be more generic). What I have is this: $variableholder = ($id!=FALSE)?'container[\''.$id.'\']':'container'; And I need it that way because if $id is FALSE then container is just and array (if not is an associative array). Don't know if I made it clear enough.

Comment: I see. Disclaimer: I'm no PHP pro. But I've never seen [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php) until today (I have used PHP on and off for maybe seven years). My first impression was: wow, this is possible with PHP? As I suspected, this language feature made it into the [list of code smells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273244/auditing-a-php-codebase) - so just as a sidenode, maybe you should not rely on such constructs at all (at least in a production setting).

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. Yeah, I chose to make an IF sentence and repeat the code with the difference that if $id is FALSE the variable has no index; if is not, it has. I just wanted to make it more elegant. Thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? (NOTE: variable variables are as bad as goto)

```
$variablename = 'array';
$key = 'index';

echo $$variablename[$key];
```

Comment: Ah, good point. You'd need to assign $$variablename to a $foobar first. But variable variables are such awful practice anyway that this conversation shouldn't exist :/