# How to access a multidimensinal PHP array, when path (level) to value is dynamic changing?

Tags: php, arrays, path

To set a value in a multidimentional array is easy. E.g.:

```
$myArray['levelA']['levelB']['levelC'] = $value
```

to read it is simple, too. E.g.:

```
$value = $myArray['levelA']['levelB']['levelC']-
```

Easy when i know how many levels are used. But what is when we do not know how many levels could occure?

What if i have a config file like this:

```
levelA.levelB.levelC.levelD = someValue
```

and what if i want to use `levelA.levelB.levelC.levelD` to map it (as a "path") to the multidimentional array, whichout knowing how deep my config could be?

Comment: You could loop down level by level. First iteration, `$foo = $myArray['a']` then `$foo = $foo['b']` then `$foo = $foo['c']`, resulting in `$foo == $myArray['a']['b']['c'] //true`

Comment: I don't think I am following what you are asking.  I am not sure what you config file is doing as that looks like a concatenation of constants that you are trying to assign another constant to. Maybe show a more real-world example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small class I wrote that would determine the number of dimensions.  You could easily modify it to do whatever you wanted, or just use the number it returns to guide your own function:

```
class DimensionCounter {

    var $i;

    public function count($array) {
        $this->i = 1;
        return $this->readArray($array);
    }

    private function readArray($array) {

        foreach($array as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->i++;
                $this->readArray($value);               
            }
            return $this->i;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, `$counter = new DimensionCounter();` `$num = $counter->count($value);` would give you the number of dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

> But what is when we do not know how many levels could occure[sic!] ?

Well it's just that you don't know how many levels there are or not.

You can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to find out easily anyway:

```
$exists = isset($myArray['levelA']['levelB']['levelC']['levelD']);
```

But I must also admit that I have some problem to understand you question.

Are you looking for:

- [use strings to access (potentially large) multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7003559/367456)

or similar?

Comment: To access the value like you did you need to know the depth of the array on coding time. That is not the way to handle it dynamically on runtime.

Comment: @DanielaWaranie: Hence the `isset` to check if. You can apply it to any depth. In the answer no value at all is accessed. Take care.