# PHP - Create a multidimensional array using dynamic functions arguments

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I need a function like this one:

```
function multi(){
    $args = get_func_args();
    $array = ????
    return $array;
}
print_r(multi('foo','bar','baz',123));
// expected result: array([foo] => array([bar] => array([baz] => 123)))
```

Comment: Does it have to be a list of args passed in or can you pass in an array? `print_r(multi(array('foo','bar','baz',123)));`

Comment: whatever I think.. `$args` in function has the args as an array.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered multiple variations of this using a reference to build-up the array:

```
function multi() {
    $path = func_get_args();      //get args
    $value = array_pop($path);    //get last arg for value

    $result = array();            //define our result
    $temp = &$result;             //reference our result

    //loop through args to create key
    foreach($path as $key) {
        //assign array as reference to and create new inner array
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = $value;               //set the value

    return $result;
}

print_r(multi('foo','bar','baz',123));
```

Comment: Yep, also see here for maybe a better way, though the `func_get_args` is cool as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/use-a-string-of-values-or-an-array-to-navigate-an-array

Comment: Now I get your link. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
    function multi(){
        $array = null;
        $args = func_get_args();
        while(count($args)>0) {
            $last = array_pop($args);
            $array = $array ? array($last=>$array) : $last;
        }
        return $array;
    }
    $data = multi('foo','bar','baz',123);
```

to update an existing value (no checks if items really exists)

```
    function set_multi($val, &$target){
        $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
        while(count($args)>0) {
            $first = array_shift($args);
            $target = &$target[$first];
        }
        $target = $val;
    }
    set_multi(456, $data, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

Comment: Good!.. How can I update a global multi array like `$array['foo']['jojo']['test'] = 345`?