# Get json value from string containing key path

Tags: javascript, php, object

I have an input array, with path like

`var path = ["foo","bar","baz"];`

And I have an object

```
var obj = {
    "foo": {
         "bar": {
              "baz": "cake"
         },
         "notbar": {
              "another": "value"
         }
    }
}
```

And i want to change the "baz" value from the path.
I know i can use

```
obj[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]] = "value";
```

but i dont know how long the array will be. both php and javascript anwsers are appreciated!

Comment: Once json decoded this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-leveled-array-by-dot-separated-key-na not sure how to implement in JS.

Comment: It's ok, php anwser is appreciated as well! thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here goes my *not pretty* but working solution:

```
function setPropertyByPath(obj, path, value) {
    if(!path || path.length === 0) return;

    var property = path[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < path.length; i++) {
      property += "." + path[i];
    }
    property = "obj." + property + " = \"" + value + "\"";
    eval(property)
}
```

Then you call

```
setPropertyByPath(obj, path, "newValue");
```

Here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9k0esrkg/)

Comment: that's actually quite smart using eval to transform string "." to object values!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function getValueByPath(obj, path) {
    var result = obj,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        try {
            result = result[path[i]];
        }
        catch (e) {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
    return result
}

function setValueByPath(obj, path, value) {
    var result = obj,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
        try {
            result = result[path[i]];
        }
        catch (e) {
            return;
        }
    }

    if (typeof value == 'object') {
        result[path[i]] = value;
    }
}
```

Given your variable initializations, `getValueByPath(obj, path)` returns `'cake'`, then set it as `setValueByPath(obj, path, 'value')`; now `getValueByPath(obj, path)` returns `'value'`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
function modify(obj, path, val) {
    var e = obj, l = path.pop();

    path.forEach(function(x) { x in e ? e = e[x] : e; });

    if (typeof val === 'undefined') return e[l];
    e[l] = val;
    return e;
}
```

You could call it as getter or a setter

```
var what = modify(obj, path);  // returns "cake"

modify(obj, path, 'new value');

var what2 = modify(obj, path);  // now return "new value", object was modified
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/57bbd4ov/)