# How to set a JSON path in array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this JSON

```
var myJSON = {
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "Foo": "Bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have this array:

```
var path = ["a", "b", "c", "foo"]
```

How can I use the path to get `Bar`?

Comment: `var x = myJSON; path.each(function(key, val) { x = x[key]; }` would be on (hopefully working) dirty way of doing it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out `Array.prototype.reduce()`. This will start at `myJSON` and walk down through each nested property name defined in `path`.

```js
var myJSON = {
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "Foo": "Bar"
      }
    }
  }
};

var path = ["a", "b", "c", "Foo"]; // capitalized Foo for you...

var val = path.reduce((o, n) => o[n], myJSON);

console.log("val: %o", val);
```

Comment: With an additional check for undefined values, this is the solution I usually go for, concise and straight-forward. Since I've come back to this answer numerous times now, I would add a bounty as a reward if this question wasn't closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @nit the dupe target's [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28682850/621962) suggests `eval()`... :/

Comment: Your answer is clearly the better one, but I'm not sure whether to vote to reopen or flag because the dupe flags go to another question as well.

Comment: Those dupe chains are interesting beasts...

Answer (score 6):

Have a variable that stores the value of the object, then iterate through the `path` accessing the next property in that variable until the next property is undefined, at which point the variable holds the end property.

```
var val = myJSON;

while (path.length) {
    val = val[path.shift()];
}

console.log(val);
```

Comment: shouldn't you check path[0] instead of val[path[0]]?

Comment: note that shifting is probably O(N) instead of O(1), though it probably depends on how its implemented

Comment: `path.reverse()` before going into the `while` (pun intended :D) and then `pop()`the hell outta it!

Comment: @canon, I get the opposite results on [this test](http://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-shift/5), with shift  coming in first, pop second, and reduce last??

Comment: @KyleMit that's because you've corrupted the test by caching `path`. So, after either the `shift()` or `pop()` test runs once, there's nothing left in `path` to process for the remaining iterations. `path.length` will be `0` from that point on, thereby skipping the `while()` loops. That said, `pop()` may be faster even with a legitimate test.

Comment: @canon, ok, here's a [fixed version](http://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-shift/5), which is now ordered pop, reduce, shift

Comment: @KyleMit looks good.

Answer (score 4):

```
function access(json, path, i) {
  if (i === path.length)
    return json;
  return access(json[path[i]], path, i + 1);
}
```

to use:

```
access(myJSON, path, 0)
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary use of recursion. Iterative approaches are generally more performant and the stack trace is also more convenient to analyse in the event of a bug.

Comment: Except that recursion is provable by induction and therefore easier to debug

Comment: It is indeed slower, but it's an interesting approach nonetheless. Recursion is like sugar for the mind :)

Comment: @twinlakes That has nothing to do with ease of debugging.

Comment: @Nit arguing that something is better for stack trace has only to do with debugging.  Also the slowdown is asymptotically negligible.

Comment: I'd say tree traversal is one of the most common cases for recursion, this is the textbook answer for OP's textbook question.  It's also easier to understand than the iterative approach.

Comment: @ParrisVarney That opinion seems to be the minority here, as both iterative approaches have more votes.

Comment: @Nit reductions are also a functional solution, not an iterative solution...

Comment: @twinlakes while it involves function calls, reduction is applied iteratively.

Comment: @canon isn't that implementation specific?  In their response, there is no sequence of steps--only one step--similar to saying that Haskell isn't functional because it's written in C.

Comment: @twinlakes I'm referring to `Array.prototype.reduce()` as defined by the [ECMAScript 5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21), because that's what bears upon this question. So, unless you're talking about reduction _in general_, and not as it pertains to this question or its answers... yes, it's applied iteratively.

Comment: This is such a basic implementation that someone has got to write a library for it and put it on npm

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJSON = {
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "Foo": "Bar"
            }
        }
    }
}

var path = ["a", "b", "c", "Foo"]


var findViaPath = function (path, object) {
    var current = object;

    path.forEach(function(e) { 
        if (current && e in current) {
            current = current[e];
        } else {
            throw new Error("Can not find key " + e)
        }
    })

    return current;
}

findViaPath(path, myJSON);
```

Comment: @canon, thanks for offering an explanation.  It's helpful to the Question OP, answer OP, and any future travelers who are looking to figure out which solution to implement.  Also, other than perhaps being less performant - I'm not sure it's over engineered.  Sure it wraps the check in a function and provides some error checking, but that's not the worst thing in the world.  It is relevant that data that looks like `Foo: false` will throw an error with `current(e)` = `current('Foo')` = `false`

Comment: @canon, it looks like `forEach` and `reduce` are both worse than just a nieve `for` loop https://jsperf.com/array-reduce-vs-foreach/9 - but they're all basically doing the same thing.  The (now fixed) error checking in this solution is something that could be added to any of the other solutions to make them more robust.

Comment: Here's [another test](http://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-shift/7). I think if we're going to add forEach to the jsPerf than we have to compare apples to apples and not include the additional error checking or function calls (both of which I think are actually good things for clarity.  What's this weird loop do? Oh, it's inside a function that tells me!  In terms of error-checking, a full path would be nice.