# PHP Config.ini file parsing with multi-level arrays

Tags: php, arrays, config, ini

I have a `config.ini` file that has a number of these types of variables:

```
site.social.twitter = "URL"
site.social.facebook = "URL"
site.social.google-plus = "URL"
```

I use PHP's built-in function to parse the INI.

```
$config = parse_ini_file(__DIR__ ."/../config.ini");
```

The next step is to get this (`site.social.twitter`) 
to become an array.

```
$config['site']['social']['twitter']
```

You could just 'explode()', but it doesn't quite get there. Is there any simpler solutions to something like this?

Comment: "Doesn't quite get there"? Can you explain what you are getting? And what you expect to get, given an example configuration?

Comment: Can you change the ini file?  Would be cleaner.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: You beat me to it.  :-) Justin - look at the PHP documentation on parse_ini_file. You can get closer to what you want by just changing your ini file to url['site.social.twitter']. That would allow you to reference it as $config['url'] and getting the array from there.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I could change the config... somewhat of a pain, as it has already been implemented throughout the site. So I will have to re-config. One thing I did think that could actually help, is by using [sections] that will help the parsing a fair bit too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so you can look at using sections and the array syntax for INI files such as:

```
[site]
social[twitter] = URL
social[facebook] = URL
social[google-plus] = URL
```

Then pass `true` as the second argument:

```
$config = parse_ini_file(__DIR__ ."/../config.ini", true);
```

Or to build using your existing INI structure (adapted from [How to access and manipulate multi-dimensional array by key names / path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path)):

```
$array = array();

foreach($config as $path => $value) {
    $temp = &$array;
    foreach(explode('.', $path) as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = $value;
}
$config = $array;
print_r($config);
```

Comment: Nice, gotta love options! Love it. Thanks @AbraCadaver

Answer (score -1):

Does simply referencing `$config['site']['social']` get you the array you want? According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) this should yield:

```
Array
    (
        [twitter] => "URL"
        [facebook] => "URL"
        [google-plus] => "URL"
    )
```

Comment: It doesn't, beucase the reference is, site.social

Comment: The reference of what? What are you trying to reference? What result do you expect? What are you actually getting?

Comment: Well, if you did, $ini = parse_ini_string("site.social.twitter"); it would still be, $ini['site.social.twitter']...... it doesn't split them up. my goal was, $ini['site']['social']['twitter']

Comment: Ah... I see. Your specification was quite unclear. You don't happen to be using a Zend framework? Then you can use [Zend_Config_ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html)