# Explode string to a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I would like to explode an array to another array based on a key.

For example :

```
[
  {
    "key": "menu.company.footer",
    "content": "this is an example"
  },
  {
    "key": "menu.company.home.foo",
    "content": "bar"
  }
]
```

Would become:

```
[
  {
    "menu": 
    {
      "company": 
      {
        "footer": "this is an example"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "menu": 
    {
      "company": 
      {
        "home": 
        {
          "foo": "bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here is what I have done:

1. Done a `foreach` through my array
2. Explode the key
3. Done a for with the count of the explode

My question is how create the parent/children system dynamically because I don't know how many level there will have.

Comment: I think your solution is not  dimension-limited. If you for over all exploded parts, you should be able to create any number of dimensions.

Comment: I was going to check it out but you need to at least post usable arrays.

Comment: @AbraCadaver : Sorry, I have updated arrays

Comment: @AbraCadaver There is a linked question with a different output, interesting too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249427/re-order-array-based-on-explode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a frequent question with a little twist.  This works:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $temp  = &$result[$k];
    $path  = explode('.', $v['key']);

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp = &$temp[$key];
    }
    $temp = $v['content'];
}
print_r($result);
```

Using a reference `&` allows you to set the `$temp` variable to a deeper nested element each time and just add to `$temp`.

- Loop through array and explode each `key` element
- Loop through exploded values and create an array with the keys, nesting as you go
- Finally, set the value of the multidimensional array to the `content` element

Also see [How to write getter/setter to access multi-level array by key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names) for something that may be adaptable.