# How to get value of an associative HTML array in PHP using a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, forms, post

Look I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="variable[var1][var2]" value="44"/>
</form>
```

I want to get the value of `variable[var1][var2]` in PHP using a string like:

```
$str = "['variable']['var1']['var2']";
echo "{$_POST{$str}}";
```

Why I need to do that?

I need it because the code that gets the value is totally dynamic and I cannot get or set manually the value using `$_POST['variable']['var1']['var2']`.

Can you help?

**NOTE**: I know this is possible to get it using `$_POST['variable']['var1']['var2']`, please don't ask me about why I'm not using this way.  Simply I need to use as above (using `$str`).

Comment: Parse your string and get keys from it.

Comment: Would `$str = "variable.var1.var2";` or similar work?

Comment: how can I  do it in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_match_all()` to get all the indexes in the string into an array:

```
$indexes = preg_match_all('/(?<=\[\')(?:[^\']*)(?=\'\])/', $str);
$indexes = $indexes[0]; // Get just the whole matches
```

Then use a loop to drill into `$_POST`.

```
$cur = $_POST;
foreach ($indexes as $index) {
    $cur = $cur[$index];
}
```

At this point `$cur` will contain the value you want.

Comment: `Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\dermaquality\test.php on line 7`

Comment: Sorry, that should be `$<=`

Answer (score 0):

You're WAY overthinking it. Anything you put in `[]` array notation in a form field's name will just become an array key. The following is LITERALLY all you need:

```
<input name="foo[bar][baz][qux]" ... />

$val = $_POST['foo']['bar']['baz']['qux'];
```

You cannot use a string as an "address" into the array, not without insanely ugly hacks like `eval`, or parsing the string and doing a loop to dig into the array.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to believe that this is a requirement.  If you could expand more on what you're trying to achieve, someone undoubtedly has a better solution.  However, I will ignore the `eval = evil` haters.

To echo:

```
eval("echo \$_POST$str;");
```

To assign to a variable:

```
eval("\$result = \$_POST$str;");
```

If you're open to another syntax then check [How to write getter/setter to access multi-level array by key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names)