# Access $_POST var based on input array name

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I might just be tired or something, but I can't figure out how I can, based on an `<input>`'s name attribute access the correct `$_POST` variable.

With simple inputs it's easy;

```
<input name="email">

$inputName = 'email';
$inputValue = $_POST[$inputName];
```

But how does it work with arrays?

```
<input name="foo[bar][0]">

$inputName = 'foo[bar][0]';
$inputValue = $_POST[$inputName]; # Obviously fails...
```

So how can I convert this to `$_POST[foo][bar][0]`, is there some built in PHP function for this?

I'm not sure how this is a duplicate of that other question seeing as he wants to access an array using `dot.separation` and I want to use the standard form name way?

A little more background; This is for a Form handling PHP class I'm building, where the user can add fields like this:

```
$form->addField(['name' => 'my[field][name]']);
```

And later when I want to fetch the value of the submitted field all I have to go by is the name specified by the user.

If I was manually doing this I would obviously just write `$_POST[foo][bar][0]` but now I can never know the name of the field and thus I have to parse it somehow.

Ok so this has expanded a bit into me having to know, based on an input name, what that input's value is, *or* if that input is selected (for select, radio elements) or if that input is part of an array of values (multiple select, checkboxes). I'd also like it to support *any* input name, such as `foo[bar][][][baz][12][]`.

If anyone has done something similar I'd love to hear about it, but it's leaning towards me writing custom code for this myself.

Comment: print_r($_POST) and you will see the post array

Comment: Why do you have to convert? If you see the `$_POST` array, you'll get `$_POST[foo][bar][0]` there itself

Comment: print_r($_POST) you will get all post data from this array

Comment: Accessing $_POST directly? Why not use any kind of framework to help sanitize and validate incoming data?

Comment: `$_POST['foo']['bar'][0]`

Comment: You'd be better off using something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names.  But there was an exact dupe.

Comment: Alright so there's nothing built in for this type of thing? I thought maybe I was onto something when I found `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'my[field][name]', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);` but that doesn't seem to do what I want :/

Answer (score -2):

you cand access like this  `$_POST['foo']['bar'][0]`;

Comment: Of course they can, but that isn't what they are asking.