# parse string as object having keys

Tags: php, string, object

I have a scenario where I have $record variable. My loop contains keys which are then parsed like `$record->{$key}`. `$keys` variable contains `['title', 'date', 'user->name']`.

Actually $record variable is a multi-dimensional object and it works fine until I have a key named as `'user->name'`.
What I want is to parse it as `$record->user->name` which I am unable to do.

```
$keys = ['title', 'date', 'location', 'user->name'];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $record->{$key};
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code, what you've tried, what you expect ?

Comment: There must be a better way that whatever you're doing to end up with `user->name` in the first please.

Comment: You could access it like this: `$record->{'user->name'};`

Comment: @JulesR - I *think* he expects the string `user->name` (the `$key` var) to be parsed as the `name` parameter of the `user` parameter of the `$record` object when doing `$record->{$key}` ...

Comment: In case you haven't noticed yet, the answer can be found in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41594358/476

Comment: D.Dimitrov, it doesn't work this way, have tried already.