# Best Practice to check for multiple array_key_exists in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access array keys of an array:

```
$attributes = $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']['SAML:ASSERTION']['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT']['SAML:ATTRIBUTE']['SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE'];
```

The way I did it works great if the response comes out nicely as I expected. 
If not, I will get something like this:

> Undefined index: SAMLP:RESPONSE

I've tried:

```
try {
  $attributes = $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']['SAML:ASSERTION']['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT']['SAML:ATTRIBUTE']['SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE'];
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Helper::console("Bad SAML RESPONSE.");
    dd('Sorry, we could not find your data. Please contact Business Customer Service at 015332266.');
}
```

I'm trying to avoid doing a lot of this `array_key_exists` check:

```
if (array_key_exists('SAMLP:RESPONSE', $xml)) {
    if (array_key_exists('SAML:ASSERTION', $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE'])) {
        if (array_key_exists('SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT', $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']['SAML:ASSERTION'])) {

            if (array_key_exists('SAML:ATTRIBUTE', $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']['SAML:ASSERTION']['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT'])) {

                if (array_key_exists('SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE', $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']['SAML:ASSERTION']['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT']['SAML:ATTRIBUTE'])) {

                    $attributes = $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']['SAML:ASSERTION']['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT']['SAML:ATTRIBUTE']['SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE'];

                }else{
                    Helper::console("['SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE'] key not exist");
                    dd('Sorry, we could not find your data. Please contact Business Customer Service at 015332266.');
                }

            }else{
                Helper::console("['SAML:ATTRIBUTE'] key not exist");
                dd('Sorry, we could not find your data. Please contact Business Customer Service at 015332266.');
            }
        }else{
            Helper::console("['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT'] key not exist");
            dd('Sorry, we could not find your data. Please contact Business Customer Service at 015332266.');
        }
    }else{

        Helper::console("['SAMLP:RESPONSE'] key not exist");
        dd('Sorry, we could not find your data. Please contact Business Customer Service at 015332266.');
    }

} else {
    Helper::console('SAMLP:RESPONSE key not exist');
    dd('Sorry, we could not find your data. Please contact Business Customer Service at 015332266.');
}
```

What would be the right way or best practice to check for something like this? How would one go about and do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though long, one `isset` will work:

```
if(isset($xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']
             ['SAML:ASSERTION']
             ['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT']
             ['SAML:ATTRIBUTE']
             ['SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE'])) {

    $attributes = $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']
                      ['SAML:ASSERTION']
                      ['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT']
                      ['SAML:ATTRIBUTE']
                      ['SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE'];
}
```

Or in PHP 7 the [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) will assign if set or assign an alternate value if not:

```
$attributes = $xml['SAMLP:RESPONSE']
                  ['SAML:ASSERTION']
                  ['SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT']
                  ['SAML:ATTRIBUTE']
                  ['SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE'] ?? null;
```

You could also check out the **Getter** function from [How to write getter/setter to access multi-level array by key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names) and pass it something like this:

```
$path = "SAMLP:RESPONSE.SAML:ASSERTION.SAML:ATTRIBUTESTATEMENT.SAML:ATTRIBUTE.SAML:ATTRIBUTEVALUE";
$attributes = get($path, $xml); //returns NULL if the path doesn't exist
```

I used a `.` separator, however you can use any separator other than `:` like `/` or `-` instead.