# php array keep pushing in the depth

Tags: php, arrays

My current code is like :

```
<?php
$item = "123.456.789.963.852.741";
$item_arr = explode(".", $item);
$inner_count = count($item_arr);
$parent_element = "myarray";

if($inner_count==3){
    $my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['order'] = $count;
    $my_array[$parent_element]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]=$my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]];
    unset($my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]);
}

if($inner_count==4){
    $my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[3]]['order'] = $count;
    $my_array[$parent_element]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[3]]=$my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[3]];
    unset($my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[3]]);
}

if($inner_count==5){
    $my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[3]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[4]]['order'] = $count;
    $my_array[$parent_element]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[3]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[4]]=$my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[3]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[4]];
    unset($my_array[$item_arr[0]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[1]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[2]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[3]]['XYZ-Key'][$item_arr[4]]);
}
```

now i want to extend it to more count (right now code is up to 5)

but the problem I can not the code in the same way

Comment: could you display the result you expect from the `$item` you gave ?

Comment: Look at the **Setter / Creator** here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names or the **For Fun** one.

Comment: wow something very close, thanks @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this manner. Just change string for your format

```
$item = "1.2.3.4.5";
$ar = explode('.', $item);
$start = '{';
$end = '}';
foreach($ar as $i) {
    $start .= '"'.$i.'":{';
    $end = '}'.$end;
}

$temp =  $start . '"order":{}' .$end; // {"1":{"2":{"3":...{"order":{}}}}}

$res = json_decode($temp,true);
```

Comment: oh yeah, nice idea, let me try that