# Multidimensional associative arrays without knowing the string keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I need to be able to take an array of unknown depth and get the keys from a specific dimension without knowing their values. For instance:

```
$deepArray = array(
    "fooArray1_1" => array(
        "fooArray2_1" => array(
           "fooA" => "3",
           "fooB" => "foo string example 1",
            ),
        "fooArray2_2" => array(
           "fooA" => "foo number 10",
           "fooB" => "foo string example",
            ),
    ),
    "fooArray1_2" => array(
        "fooA" => "foo number 102",
        "fooB" => "foo string example 3",
    ),
);
```

I would like to be able to get the key from `$deepArray[0][1]` where in this instance should be `fooArray2_2`.

Comment: [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) should be helpful for you to work this out

Comment: For traversing a structure of unknown depth you should use a recursive function.

Comment: So just the key `"fooArray2_2"` or you want the data under that key?

Comment: @AbraCadaver and splash58. Thank you for helping. You have solved my issue. I tried to upvote both of you, but I don't have permission.

Comment: If you wanted the key then please accept @splash58's answer, if you wanted the data under that key then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getKey($arr, $path) {
    // save last step
    $s = array_pop($path);
    // go through the array to the desired point 
    foreach($path as $x) {
        $arr = $arr[array_keys($arr)[$x]];
    }
    // get target key  
    return array_keys($arr)[$s]; 
}

echo getKey($deepArray, [0,1]); // fooArray2_2
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/957660)

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the key, but if you really want the data under that key; here's an example from my answer [How to write getter/setter to access multi-level array by key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names), modified to use `array_values` to index numerically:

```
function get_by_offsets($path, $array) {
    $temp = &$array;

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp = array_values($temp);
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    return $temp;
}

$result = get_by_offsets([0, 1], $deepArray); //returns NULL if the path doesn't exist
```

Yields the data under `$deepArray['fooArray1_1']['fooArray2_2']`:

```
Array
(
    [fooA] => foo number 10
    [fooB] => foo string example
)
```