# Unset element in multi-dimensional array by path

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to remove an element in a multidimensional array.

The element which is needs to be removed is given by a string like `globals.connects.setting1`. This means I'm intend to modify an array like this:

```
// Old Array
$old = array(
    "globals" => array(
        "connects" => array(
            "setting1" => "some value",
            "setting2" => "some other value",
            "logging" => array()),
    "someOtherKey" => 1
));

// After modification
$new = array(
    "globals" => array(
        "connects" => array(
            "setting2" => "some other value",
            "logging" => array()),
    "someOtherKey" => 1
));
```

Unfortunately I do not know either the "depth" of the given string nor the exact structure of the array. I'm looking for a function like `unsetElement($path, $array)` which returns the array `$new`, if the array `$old` and `globals.connects.setting1` is given as argument.

I'd like to avoid the use of the `eval()` function due to security reasons.

Comment: Your code "example" is not valid PHP (and I'm not talking about the ellipsis). And this question, with valid code examples, has been answered several times on [so].

Comment: Discussed on Meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363695/mark-as-duplicate-of-old-answer-after-adding-to-old-answer-or-not so unfortunately there will be some drive-by downvoters to everything.

Comment: I'm sorry for the (stupid) question. In fact i was aware of the cited question (which this question is a duplicate of). But I had something in mind, that using unset in the context of references will remove the reference and not an element fo the referenced object. Obviously I was wrong. I'm sorry.

Thanks a lot to everybody participating in the conversation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  $testArr = [
        "globals" => [
            "connects" => [
                'setting1' => [
                    'test' => 'testCon1',
                ],
                'setting2' => [
                    'abc' => 'testCon2',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'someOtherKey' => [],
    ];

$pathToUnset = "globals.connects.setting2";

    function unsetByPath(&$array, $path) {
        $path = explode('.', $path);
        $temp = & $array;

        foreach($path as $key) {
            if(isset($temp[$key])){
                if(!($key == end($path))) $temp = &$temp[$key];
            } else {
               return false; //invalid path
            }
        }
        unset($temp[end($path)]);
    }

    unsetByPath($testArr, $pathToUnset);
```