# Can I create a chain of PHP object references programmatically?

Tags: php, arrays, object, reference, key

For example, I know how to take an arbitrary set of keys and use them to make object references like this...

```
$arr = array("A", "B", "C");
foreach($arr as $key):
    echo $obj->{$key} . "\n";
endforeach;
// prints $obj->A, $obj->B and $obj->C
```

But what if I have multiple levels of references within an object that I want to access?  Is it possible to add more arrow operators on the fly?

```
$arr = array(array("A", "B"),
             array("C", "D", "E"),
             array("F"));
foreach($arr as $key_arr):
    // ???
endforeach;
// prints $obj->A->B, $obj->C->D->E, $obj->F
```

Comment: In your second example.. what do you expect the values to be?

Comment: FYI... Here are some examples that you can adapt to using objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to loop over the names and maintain a reference on the last object before to echo.

```
foreach($arr as $key_arr) {
    $ref = $obj ;
    foreach ($key_arr as $item) {
        $ref = $ref->{$item} ; // $obj->A, then $obj->A->B
    }
    echo $ref ;
}
```

- `$ref = $obj`
- Then `$ref = $ref->A`
- Then `$ref = $ref->B` so `$ref->A->B`
- And so on...
- Then echo the last reference