# return specific array form from function

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

and this function

```
function change($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $form[$key+5][$value-1] = $key-$value;
    }
    return $form;
}
change($array);
```

in it the form that i want to rearrange the array in is `$form[$key+5][$value-1] = $key-$value;` but i want to make it defined by a parameter like this

```
function change($array, $form) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $form;
    }
    return $form;
}
$x = change($array, $arr[$key+5][$value-1] = $key-$value);
$y = change($array, $arr[$key+5][$key+100] = $key+$value);
```

how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody will bash all of the evils of `eval` but if it is not user supplied (un-trusted) data, then this works:

```
function change($array, $form) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        eval("\$result$form;");
    }
    return $result;
}
```

You need to call it with a string as shown:

```
$x = change($array, '[$key+5][$value-1] = $key-$value');
$y = change($array, '[$key+5][$key+100] = $key+$value');
```

This builds a string that looks like this: `$result[$key+5][$key+100] = $key+$value;` and evaluates it as PHP code.

It would be a lot more work, but you could pass in something to parse and adapt it to [How to access and manipulate multi-dimensional array by key names / path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path).

Comment: everytime i read about `eval` i understood why its dangerous but never cared about it because i never thought or knew how to use it in any of my codes - now i know

Comment: is there other methods to mimic this without `eval` too?