# PHP Access a Nested Object Property Using Variable

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, php-7

I am using PHP7.

I have an Object I am trying to parse:

```
$RECORD = {
    'name' => 'Stephen Brad Taylor', 
    'address' => '432 Cranberry Hills, Pittsburg',
    'phone' => '708 865 456', 
    'Account' => (Object Vendor/Entity/User) {
         'email' => 'INeedThisEmail@pleaseHelp.com' // I want to access this property.
         'id' => 34,
         'accessible' => ['email', 'id]
    } 
}
```

I have an array which I am using to select certain fields from `RECORD`:

```
$fieldnames = [
     'name',
     'address',
     'phone',
     'Account["email"]'
];
```

I am trying to parse the `fieldnames` from `RECORD` as follows:

```
$data[] 
foreach($fieldnames as $k => $fieldname) {
    $data[k] = $RECORD->$fieldname
}
```

The method above works for the first-level attributes: `name, address, and phone`. However, `email` returns null.

I have tried the following below and none have worked:

```
$data[k] = RECORD->${$fieldname}

$propertyName = '$RECORD->$fieldname' 
$data[k] = ${$propertyName}
```

Does anyone know a way to access an object's properties using a string ***from an object reference***?

Much gratitude <3

Comment: Is the nested level only 2 levels deep? How does more than 2 look like?

Comment: is the account itself not an object? what happens with print_r($RECORDS->Account);

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but it seems like you're trying to convert it to an array? IF so, try: `$array = json_decode(json_encode($RECORD), true);`

Comment: If you're using CakePHP and your objects implement `ArrayAccess` (which entities do by default), then don't reinvent the wheel, try [**`\Cake\Utility\Hash`**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html) and its path syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Account["email"]` directly as a property accessor, it won't be split up to find the nested property. You need to parse it yourself.

```
foreach($fieldnames as $k => $fieldname) {
    if (preg_match('/^(.*)\["(.*)"\]$/', $fieldname, $match) {
        $data[$k] = $RECORD->{$match[1]}->{$match[2]};
    } else {
        $data[$k] = $RECORD->$fieldname;
    }
}
```

Also, you need `$` in `$k`.

This code only works for 1 level deep. If you need to deal with arbitrary levels, you'll have to write a recursive procedure. See [How to access and manipulate multi-dimensional array by key names / path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names) for examples of how to code this.

Answer (score 1):

I use anonymous functions for such cases. (PHP 7.4)

```
    $index = fn($item) => $item->dotaItem->prop_def_index;
    if (get_class($collection) === Collection::class) {
        $index = fn($item) => $item->prop_def_index;
    }
```