# PHP: Access Object Properties by String

Tags: php

Okay, Lets say I have an object with properties like this:

```
$testObj->wind->windi // this returns a value like 100 mph
$testObj->wind->windii // this returns a value like 110 mph
```

I need to access a property but I don't know what property explicitly, Instead I have a string like this:

```
$str = 'wind->windii';
```

Calling predefined values works:

```
echo $testObj->wind->windii; //results in 110 mph
```

**The Problem:** I need a way to get the values without hard coding the actual properties:

```
echo $testObj->$str; //and have it result in 110 mph
```

I thought this was a variable variables situation but I had no luck getting that to work and after a few hours of frustration I'm asking for help

*edit:
I also need to mention that the object name changes as well so we can't hard code $testObj but rather be able to take any object and any string and get it's properties

Also, bracket notation isn't working, it results in "Undefined property: stdClass::$wind->elevation"

**For those following at home, this is the var_dump of $testObj**

```
object(stdClass)#299 (2) {
  ["snow"]=>
  object(stdClass)#315 (3) {
    ["elevation"]=>
    string(5) "365.4"
    ["results"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["status"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["wind"]=>
  object(stdClass)#314 (5) {
    ["elevation"]=>
    string(5) "365.4"
    ["windi"]=>
    string(7) "100 mph"
    ["windii"]=>
    string(7) "110 mph"
    ["windiii"]=>
    string(7) "115 mph"
    ["status"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path?

Comment: @NigelRen Except that's for arrays, not objects.

Comment: @NigelRen that is perfect, if it was only for objects!

Comment: So we can close with Nigel's link then?

Comment: @NigelRen Well... if you can tweak to make this better, maybe an answer would probably be better for this one? Rather than closing as a dupe?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Here's a thought, why can I upvote my own tweets but can't upvote my own questions hahahaha

Comment: @CodeJunkie LOL! I know huh? I even tried it myself once, and twice... just to see if things changed; alas... they haven't :D

Comment: This is a classic case of r/choosingbeggars. I'll give it a shot

Comment: @NigelRen Well it's all the same to me :) If you want, I can leave it open and have you post an answer. Or, let me know now and I can use the link you posted above as a duplicate. I'm in no hurry ;-) nor eager lol

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It worked :D -- in 2 days time I will accept my own answer hahaha

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks, enjoy your TV show lol

Comment: Right on @CodeJunkie cheers :) Glad to see that this one got resolved.

Comment: @NigelRen I just realized something Nigel, this is my second encounter with you. You've answered one of my previous questions... Thank you sir, you truly are an expert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have working code.
With mental support from @NigelRen
Emotional support from @FunkFortyNiner
**And most of the code from [this question about arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path)**

**Test Object:**

```
$obj = json_decode('{"snow":{"elevation":"365.4","results":"6","status":1},"wind":{"elevation":"365.4","windi":"100 mph","windii":"110 mph","windiii":"115 mph","status":1}}');
```

**Test Directory:**

```
$path = 'wind:windii';
```

**Getter:**

```
  function get($path, $obj) {
    $path = explode(':', $path);
    $temp =& $obj;

    foreach($path as $key) {
      $temp =& $temp->{$key};
    }
    return $temp;
  }
  var_dump(get($path, $obj)); //dump to see the result
```

**Setter:**

```
  function set($path, &$obj, $value=null) {
    $path = explode(':', $path);
    $temp =& $obj;

    foreach($path as $key) {
      $temp =& $temp->{$key};
    }

    $temp = $value;
  }
  //Tested with:
  set($path, $obj, '111');
```

Answer (score 3):

you can change it to this :

```
$str1 = 'wind';
$str2 = 'windii';
echo $testObj->{$str1}->{$str2};
```

Comment: No, So the problem is that the string is unknown, not to mention the dimensions of the properties, so I can't hard code individual strings since I have no idea how many I need yet.

Comment: you said I have a string like it : { $str = 'wind->windii' }. yes or no? if you have that variable, you can split it with "->" separator and now you have an array of properties

Comment: To make your answer work I'd have to concatenate ->$str# to $testObj and then evaluate the entire string.... Which is exactly the problem but now we've added $testObj to the beginning of the string. Thanks for your input though

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can access properties dynamically such as:

`

```
class test {
    public testvar;
}
$newtest = new test();
$property = "testvar"
$newtest->{"testvar"} //or $newtest->{$property};
```

`

Depending on what you are doing you can you a foreach loop to get the key value pair as well.

`

```
foreach($newtest as $key=>$val){
}
```

`