# How to dynamically unset nested array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Lets suppose I have this array:

```
$doc = array(
    'nfe' => array(
        'inf' => array(
            'det' => array(
                'emit' => array(
                     'name' => 'My name'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

and another array with the keys I want to unset (in order):

```
$keys = ['nfe', 'inf', 'det', 'emit']
```

How can I dynamically do this:

```
unset($doc['nfe']['inf']['det']['emit']);
```

Based on both arrays `$doc` and `$keys` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing around with some of my code from [How to access and manipulate multi-dimensional array by key names / path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
function unsetter($path, &$array) {
    $temp =& $array;
    $last = array_pop($path);

    foreach($path as $key) {
        $temp =& $temp[$key];
    }
    unset($temp[$last]);
}
```

Here is an `eval` method:

```
function unsetter($path, &$array) {
    $path = "['" . implode("']['", $path) . "']";
    eval("unset(\$array{$path});");
}
```

Comment: Wow, I would never think of a solution like this. It worked like a charm. Thank you!