# PHP - Get array reference by his string name

Tags: php

If I do this:

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three"];

$array_copy = "$array"; // or "{$array}"
```

I doesn't get the original array but instead a string conversion of it. ¿Is there any way to acomplish this task? To get the array reference by his string name.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I am aware of this:

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three"];

$array_copy = $"array";
```

or

```
$name = "array";

$array_copy = $$name
```

But I need to achive this in any situation. Example:

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three" => ["four"] ];

$sub_array = "{$array['three']}"; // this returns an string, not the array ["four"]
```

I hope is more clear now.

**Edit 2**

Let's put it in other way. Imagine you need that an user input (string) be able to access the content of any declared variable. Example:

> $customer = [ "name"=>"Peter", "address"=> ["street"=>"5th", "number"=>1969] ];
>
> $variable_name = $_GET["varname"];
>
> var_export( $$variable_name ); // What can write the user to print $customer["address"] array?

Comment: Are you looking for `${'array'}`? See [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: `${'array'}['three']` after your edit then... Did you read the link?

Comment: Can you give an example of the scenario where this is necessary? Seems like there might be a better way.

Comment: Hello @Jeto ${'array'}['three'] is not working for me cause I have no control of the syntax, it can be ${'array'}['three'] or ${'array'}['three']['two'] or anything. For this reason a need it to be all string. Thanks for your time

Comment: @Don't Panic its a templating situation, I need to pass a variable name to a child template. Later, this name has to be parsed in the child, for accessing the data contained in the parent variable (for example as an argument for a "foreach loop"). Its a bit confusing but maybe you're right, I need to think it more and do it in another way.

Comment: I added a new better example in Edit 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access and manipulate multi-dimensional array by key names / path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path)

Comment: @Jeto unfortunately not. I use this technique you suggested for other purposes, What I need in this case is the answer to Edit 2. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a function that takes a path such as `customer.address` as a parameter to retrieve the `address` index of the `$customer` array automatically:

```
$customer = ['name' => 'Peter', 'address' => ['street' => '5th', 'number' => 1969]];

/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param string $path A dot-separated property path.
 * @param mixed $default
 * @return mixed
 */
function getArrayValue(array $array, string $path, $default = null)
{
  $parts = explode('.', $path);
  return array_reduce($parts, static function ($value, $part) use ($default) {
    return $value[$part] ?? $default;
  }, $array);
}

/**
 * @param string $path A dot-separated path, whose first part is a var name available in the global scope.
 * @param mixed $default
 * @return mixed
 */
function getGlobalArrayValue(string $path, $default = null)
{
  @list($varName, $propertyPath) = explode('.', $path, 2);
  return getArrayValue($GLOBALS[$varName] ?? [], $propertyPath, $default);
}

echo getGlobalArrayValue('customer.name'), PHP_EOL; // Peter
echo getGlobalArrayValue('customer.address.street'), PHP_EOL; // '5th'
echo getGlobalArrayValue('customer.address.idontexist', 'somedefaultvalue'), PHP_EOL; // 'somedefaultvalue'
echo getGlobalArrayValue('idontexist.address', 12); // 12
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/O6h2P**

Comment: Thanks, that's very usefull

Answer (score 1):

because you equal to string, just do it directly

```
$array_copy = $array
```

but copy is just copy, not a referense, if you want reference you should write like this

```
$array_copy = &$array
```

but there are should be reasons to get the reference

or if you have some variable with array name then you can do like this

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three"];
$arrayName = 'array';

$array_copy = $$arrayName;
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. What I need is a copy, not a reference. But I need to get it directlly by a string, I can`t use the common $array expression. Thanks

Comment: @JorgeLuis, i edited my answer, may be last part will satisfy you

Comment: Thank you @Dmitry Reutov. I just updated my post also to cover this alternative. :D