# Turning x.x.x.x string into list address (???)

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, key

This is a difficult problem to explain.  I have a string that looks like "system.cpu.total.pct" that I'm pulling from a json configuration file.  This particular format is required elsewhere in my program so I cannot change it.

This "system.cpu.total.pct" specifies what field I'm interested in snagging out of metricbeat (in Elasticsearch).

I need to convert this into a list address (? is that what to call it ?) so that I can snag stuff out of an array of database results I'm calling 'rawData'.  Right now I'm doing this:

```
if sourceSet == "system.cpu.total.pct":
    dataArray.append(rawData['hits']['hits'][thisRecord]["_source"]['system']['cpu']['total']['pct'])
```

But that's no good, obviously, because the result is hard-coded.

How can I instead write something like

```
dataArray.append(rawData['hits']['hits'][thisRecord]["_source"]["system.cpu.total.pct"])
```

that will work for any arbitrary string?

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify what the code would actually do? `system.cpu.total.pct` would be transformed into what?

Comment: "that's no good, obviously, because the result is hard-coded" - you could use `query_str.split('.')` to get the elements and then iterate over calls to the dictionary's `get()` method.

Comment: I have duplicate links for PHP and JavaScript, the same general approach should work for Python: [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-write-getter-setter-to-access-multi-level-array-by-key-names) [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arays-by-string-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
if sourceSet == "system.cpu.total.pct":
    d = rawData['hits']['hits'][thisRecord]["_source"]
    for t in sourceSet.split('.'):
        d = d[t]

    dataArray.append(d)
```