# Check, if array-"chain" exists

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array like:

```
  $array = ['foo'=>['bar' => ['value' => 'test']]];
```

Now I would like to get the `value`:

```
echo $array['foo']['bar']['value']; // 'test'
```

Now my problem begins: Sometimes the array is missing some parts. Like `bar`. Now I would get an error, because the index `bar` does not exist.

I can do an `array_key_exists` search in this. But I'd also have to do this on `foo` and `value`.

So my question is: Is there a good way to check the "chain" of array indices?

My first try was something like

```
strpos(json_encode($array), 'value') > 0
```

But this is returns a false positive if an array like

```
  $array = ['foo'=>['value' => 'test']];
  echo $array['foo']['bar']['value']; // error
```

comes up.

Comment: Use the NULL coalescing operator: `echo $array['foo']['bar']['value'] ?? 'not present';`

Comment: `isset($array['foo']['bar']['value'])`

Comment: You can always check isset(). A second way is to check the array that is generated after running array_keys($array).

Comment: `isset` is the way, but this might help, returns NULL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path