# Convert comma separated string with value to nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I am receiving csv data as separate strings which I am trying to convert into nested arrays, and then json.

The strings I am receiving are like this, where the last element is the value.

```
$str1 = "name,firstname,Bob";
$str2 = "name,lastname,Dylan";
```

Here I need to convert the strings into nested arrays which would be equivalent to the arrays below. This is the bit I am struggling with.

```
$arr1 = ["name" => ["firstname" => "Bob"]];
$arr2 = ["name" => ["lastname" => "Dylan"]];
```

I can then use a array_merge_recursive to combine them

```
$merged = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2);
```

After that I can convert the merged array into json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access and manipulate multi-dimensional array by key names / path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pass in your dynamic number of strings to a loop.
2. Parse the comma-separated values.
3. Use the values to push data into your array structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/erQco))

```
$strings = ["name,firstname,Bob", "name,lastname,Dylan"];
$result = [];
foreach ($strings as $csv) {
    [$level1, $level2, $value] = str_getcsv($csv);
    $result[$level1][$level2] = $value;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'name' => 
  array (
    'firstname' => 'Bob',
    'lastname' => 'Dylan',
  ),
)
```

---

Or more succinctly, you can push directly from the array destructuring step to achieve the same result as above: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DDgAi))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($strings as $csv) {
    [$level1, $level2, $result[$level1][$level2]] = str_getcsv($csv);
}
var_export($result);
```