# Get value of dynamic sub-array, in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Not sure if my question is clear, but here's what I'm trying to achieve. Let’s say I have a multidimensional array like so:

```
$arr['client1']**['dog']['Jack']**
$arr['client2']['cat']['Stacy']
```

How can I get the second portion of the array (between **), knowing it can be anything. For client 3, it could be a crocodile. For Client 4, it could be a car.

So I'm looking to "build" the structure of the array, dynamically. Something like so:

```
$arr['client1']{partBetweenThe**InTheExemple}
```

`{partBetweenThe**InTheExemple}` would be constructed "on the fly" (hence, the dynamically).

EDIT: Hopefully some clarifications...

The array changes every time. Basically, I'm building an addon to poll any API on the web. The data structure I'm getting can be anything. So what I need to do is build the key combination "on the fly", with variables.

In the exemple above, my variable would be something like `$query = ['dog']['Jack']` and to get the value, I would poll it like so (from a logistic perspective, I know this doesn't work):

`$arr['client1'][$query]` or `$arr['client1']$query` or `$arr['client1']{$query}`

Comment: Would `car` be in a variable or what? Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path/27930028#27930028

Comment: Can you show us a proper/real example of an array, how you would create it and explain what it's for? That would make it much clearer for us to suggest a good solution.

Comment: You can use `array_keys()` to get the keys of an array. So `array_keys($array['client1'])[0]` will be the first key.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I've clarified above...

Comment: If the response from the API is dynamic and changes, how would you even know what keys to search for? How would you create the `$query` to begin with?

Comment: @M.Eriksson The idea, is to be able to use the same code, for any API result. Your code below seem to be working fine. I'll test more thoroughly tomorrow. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define the query as an array with each level as an element. Then we can iterate through that and check if we find a matching key in the response:

```php
function findInArray(array $query, array $data)
{
    foreach ($query as $key) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $data)) {
            // The key was not found, abort and return null
            return null;
        }

        // Since the key was found, move to next level
        $data =& $data[$key];
    }
    
    return $data;
}

// Example response
$response = [
    'client1' => [
        'dog' => [
            'Jack' => 'Some value',
        ],
    ]
];

// Define the query as an array
$query = ['dog', 'Jack'];

$result = findInArray($query, $response['client1']);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/WjXTn

Comment: Your solution seems to be working. Here, I've modified you code with a more complex array: https://3v4l.org/m4seY.

Comment: Yes, the above should work regardless how many levels you have.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

So since the array's structure can't be changed this will return the client if the structure remains ['client']['animal']['name'].

```
$clients = [
    'client1' => [
        'dog' => [
            'Jack' => []
        ]
    ],
    'client2' => [
        'cat' => [
            'Stacy' => []
        ]
    ]
];

$animal = 'dog';
$name = 'Jack';

foreach ($clients as $client => $options) {
    if (
        array_key_exists($animal, $options) &&
        array_key_exists($name, $options[$animal])
    ) {
        echo $client;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the array I'm getting is from an API. I can't change its structure.