# Can i use variable in mutli level array naming

Tags: php, associative-array

```
<?php
$array['a']['b']['c']['d'] = "foo";
$many = ['b']['c'];

echo $array['a']$many['d'];
?>
```

Is there any way to make this work?

I have try with {} around but i cannot make it work.
The goal i try to achieve is to replace b and c cause I have
['a']['children']['b']['children']['c']['d'].

Since i can have many children i want a way to avoid to write it every time dans replace
['children']['b']['children']['c'] as a variable cause A and D will always by there.

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Answer (score 0):

You can't write braces("[", "]") as a variable value.

I'm not sure, it'll help you or not, the intermediate keys are sending here seperated by underscore as 2nd param, the 3rd is the value,

```
<?php

$array = array('a' => array());

setArrVal($array['a'], 'b_children_c_childs', 'Argentina');

//echo '<pre>';print_r($array);echo '</pre>';

function setArrVal(&$array, $indexes, $value)
{
    $index = explode('_', $indexes);
    
    $temp =& $array;
    foreach ($index as $i)
    {
        $temp[$i] = array();
        $temp =& $temp[$i];
    }

    $temp['d'] = $value;
}
?>
```

The array structure will be:

Array
(

```
[a] => Array

    (

        [b] => Array

            (

                [children] => Array

                    (

                        [c] => Array

                            (

                                [childs] => Array

                                    (

                                        [d] => Argentina

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: He has a dynamic string of indexes, not separate variables.

Comment: These 2 sign [ & ] can't from any variable value.

Comment: I know. But you can parse it into an array and then loop through the array, accessing the indexes dynamically. See the duplicate question.

Comment: Hmm, the idea is fine, form array element by processing intermediate keys. 
Can you please write 2/3 sample array elements?

Comment: Can't fit it into a comment.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow morning, interesting problem :)

Comment: finally i succed with an answer looking like this one.

Thanks for help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929875/how-to-access-and-manipulate-multi-dimensional-array-by-key-names-path