# Is there any way to index an array with a sequence of indexes in a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Having: 
an array $a, 
a variable `$indexes = "[\"level1\"][\"level2\"][\"level3\"]"`;

Is there any way to access `$a["level1"]["level2"]["level3"]`?

The situation is that the number of indexes that this function will handle can change. So this is the reason the indexes comes in a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use strings to access (potentially large) multidimensional arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003559/use-strings-to-access-potentially-large-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: This question is a Super Duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+variable+variables+array+keys

Answer (score 0):

Hope this simple solution will help you out.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788346)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Here we are retrieving levels
$indexes = '["level1"]["level2"]["level3"]';
preg_match_all('/(?<=")[\w]+(?=")/', $indexes,$matches);
$levels=$matches[0];

//this is the sample array
$array=$tempArray=array(
    "level1"=>array(
        "level2"=>array(
            "level3"=>"someValue"
        )
    )
);
//here we are iterating over levels to get desired output.

foreach($levels as $level)
{
    $tempArray=$tempArray[$level];
}
print_r($tempArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use `string` for `$indexes`, use an `array`.

For simple retrieving, you can use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$result = array_reduce($indexes, function ($array, $index) {
    return isset($array[$index]) ? $array[$index] : null;
}, $array);
```

Note that value defaults to `null` when there is no such index in the array.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e12700116ea4a8131559891a1c03c5bfcca34ff1).

If you want some more sophisticated stuff, check out [a library I wrote some time ago](https://github.com/Sevavietl/Arrays) for situations, when you also need to add items to an array and check for the existence:

```
var_dump(isset($array[['foo', 'bar']]));

var_dump($array[['foo', 'bar']]);

$array[['foo', 'bar']] = 'baz';

unset($array[['foo', 'bar']]);
```

They are all valid usage examples for existence checking, retrieving the element, writing the element and deleting the element respectively.